# Logging & Auditing mechanism within Argo CD

Tags: argocd

Is there a direct way to implement logging and auditing mechanisms within Argo CD to capture detailed information about each deployment, including changes made, success/failure status, and who initiated the deployment?

For this will I have to set appropriate flags in the `argocd-server` deployment? i.e. `--audit-log-enabled true` to the `args` section?

I am not able to understand this. I want to implement logging and auditing mechanisms within Argo CD to capture these informations and then I want to securely store these logs for compliance and troubleshooting purposes.